# Sliding Points on a curve in GeoNodes

Tags: animation, node-editor, constraints, geometry-nodes, curve-modifier

Is there a way to animate instance points on a curve in geometry nodes?
I am thinking of something similar to the follow path constraint, with an easy offset value to manipulate.
I have a curve object on which I want the instanced objects to slide along.
The offset between the instanced objects should stay constant.[image: nodetree-screenshot]

Edit: Also it would be cool if the sliding would loop on the curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]you can use this node setup:

[image]

if you animate e.g. the start value you will get:

Comment: Thank you very much! What kind of node is the "Equal" node, i cant find it in the standart math node.

Comment: It’s in Blender 3.1

Comment: If my answer helped you, please check the checkmark left to my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I found "Equal" in the compare node. As a second question it also would be cool if the sliding would loop, do you know a way to do this? :)

Comment: Since this is a new question please open up a new question and I will help you

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249144/animate-instance-points-on-a-curve-in-a-loop-geo-nodes i did, thank you :)