# Animate Instance Points on a curve in a Loop (geo-nodes)

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, curve-modifier

Is there a way to animate instance points on a curve in a loop in geometry nodes? I have a curve object on which I want the instanced objects to slide along, without creating a gap after them. The offset between the instanced objects should stay constant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can sample the curve's  0-1 `Curve Parameter` on its `Points` domain. Then a function of it is available to a *Set Position* on the points the curve has been converted to.

To get the loop, the `Curve Parameter` is offset, and *Wrapped* back to the 0-1 range. The position of that modified parameter is sampled back off the curve:

[image]

Once the points are offset down the curve, a collection of objects can be instanced on them. The offset can be exposed in the GN modifier, and keyframed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot! Now I am struggeling in a different project, with a similar problem. I would really appreciate if you have any ideas on it. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250809/animate-instance-points-in-a-loop-on-a-surface-geo-nodes