# Animate instance points in a Loop on a Surface (Geo-Nodes)

Tags: animation, node-editor, geometry-nodes

Is there a way to animate instance points on a mesh surface, that is driven by a curve, in a loop in geometry nodes? I tried to manipulate the node setup for animating the looping points on a curve, to fit my needs, but it gives me this error.

Edit: For Clarification: I want to achieve something similar to a particle curve guide in geometry nodes. [image: Node tree animating Points on Mesh]

Comment: Just to clarify, is the _curve_ a geometric loop (cyclic), the _animation_ a temporal loop.. or both? And is  the curve on the surface of another object?

Comment: Only the points on the surface should loop (alternatively maybe new points could be created while moving, so the points don't leave a gap behind them, when they move). The curve itself is not looped. I wanted to use a curve so I can draw the animated particles following a path around the scene (similar to a curve guide in particle systems). The curve is not on a surface. Thank you :)

Comment: i think it is possible with a very complicated node setup and with the help of the curve trim node. But i think this isn't worth the effort. i would use the good old "follow path constraint" which is much easier for that case and wait for GN to get some new nodes...but i am curious how Robin's solution will look like

Comment: Sorry for delay.. AFK.. what I'm imaging is some sort of ribbon (visible or invisible) 
 through the scene with instances continuously sweeping down it? Not so different from previous answer? Or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: Hello. @Leo.. you've recently mentioned this again, and I'm sorry, personally I'm still not clear exactly what you need. Is there a particular part of the surface  you want followed? All of it with different paths? An illustration would really help.

Answer (score 2):

ok, i figured a way out...but ...it is not nice and pretty dirty and tedious.

So you can use this node setup:

[image]

For every new instance you want to have to have to copy the framed notes and join them again in to the existing join geometry node.

And you have to change the value in the first add node of the frame.

It should be a bit cleaner if you would make a nodegroup from the nodes in the frame with input "value" for the add node.

result:

[image]

Here a bit cleaner setup:

[image]

[image]