# Point Translate Node effect in 3.0

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, curve-modifier

in a previous version of Blender I used an Array Modifier + Curve Modifier + Point Translate Node in Geometry Nodes to create a 'particles follow path' effect like this one:

[image: particles follow path effect]

To animate the instances I changed the X value in the Point Translate node. The is the tree I used:

[image: particles follow path effect]

Now I'd like to recreate the effect using Blender 3.0 but Point Translate is now a legacy node. I've managed to create the instances using the points of a curve but I'm not sure how to 'offset' their position. Any ideas?

[image: particles follow path effect]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you use a very slight variation on the group in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249232/35559)?

**Edit:** Thanks to @Chris ' edit, below, this is a revised, more economical version, for Blender 3.0:

[image]

I don't know why the gif is so glitchy.. the animation is smooth...

[image]

[image] for Blender 3.0, (revised)

---

Here the setup for 3.1:

[image]

Small remarks:

- looks like the capture attribute isn't necessary

[image]

Comment: Thank you Robin, this works. I had tried to use the group from that answer but I couldn't change it properly as you did.

Comment: @Robin Betts: great answer, i like "loosing" against a solution from which i can learn and that's so much better than mine!  i updated the answer for 3.1 - hope you don't mind. +1 -> my gif is as glitchy as yours ;)

Comment: @Chris Of _course_ I don't mind! I'm just feeling guilty now, because your way gets rid of so much crud. It will work on the other answer too, no? A little job today.. tidying up after my own doziness :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use this node setup to get that effect (with **ONLY** using GN):

[image]

[image]

Note: This setup is NOT perfect. It works "kind of". But just in the "middle" of the curve, else the instances will be compressed. So either you try to improve it (please let me know if you solved that) or just lengthen your curve at start and end as a workaround.

BTW: very nice animation...!

Comment: Thank you Chris!, but I found Robin's answer more robust.

Comment: No problem. And you are right!