# How can i offset my points along the curve (Geometry Nodes)?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I instanced a bunch of points along a curve with a modified radius.

I'm trying to make those point translate along the curve, but keep instancing at the beginning and disappearing at the end. Like an offset along the curve.

Is there anyway to achieve this ?

Thank you !

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file so that we don't have to rebuild everything on our own

Answer (score 2):

You can use solution based on Robin Betts answer from here: [Animate Instance Points on a curve in a Loop (geo-nodes)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249144/animate-instance-points-on-a-curve-in-a-loop-geo-nodes)

Something like that:

[image]

File (blender 3.1):

[image]